# Problema com Parâmetros ireport 4.0.1

Tags: oracle, ireport

Boa noite,
Estou fazendo um relatório no Ireport 4.0.1 e estou tendo dificuldade com alguns parâmetros. Tenho um relatório de faturamento que necessitaainsira o código aqui de alguns filtros. Os mesmos são,  o intervalo de datas inicial e final, o tipo  de operação e a empresa. Esses são filtros obrigatórios e funcionam normalmente. Porém, estou tentando acrescentar mais dois parâmetros, um que filtre  por produto e outro por vendedor, porém, mesmo  esses dois não sendo parâmetros obrigatórios se eu buscar o relatório deixando esses dois campos vazios, ele não me retorna nada, já preenchendo todos os parâmetros e me retornam os dados normalmente. Gostaria que de  saber o que preciso  fazer para que esses dois parâmetros sejam ignorados caso não sejam preenchidos. Segue a query :

```
select
TO_CHAR(cab.codparc,'00000000') AS CODPARC,
par.razaosocial,
TO_CHAR(cab.codparc,'00000000')||' - '||par.razaosocial as parceiro,
par.razaosocial,
TO_CHAR(cab.dtmov,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DATA,
TO_CHAR(CAB.dtmov,'HH:MM') AS HORA,
cab.codtipoper,
cab.nunota,
cab.numnota,
cab.codemp,
cab.tipmov,
ite.codprod,
pro.descrprod,
ite.qtdneg,
ite.codvol,
ite.vlrunit,
ven.apelido,
cid.nomecid,
pro.pesoliq,
(ite.vlrtot-ite.vlrdesc)*(case when cab.tipmov='D' then -1 else 1 end) as vlrtot
from tgfcab cab
inner join tgfite ite on (ite.nunota=cab.nunota)
inner join tgfpro pro on (ite.codprod=pro.codprod)
inner join tgfpar par on (cab.codparc=par.codparc)
inner join tgftop tpo on (cab.codtipoper=tpo.codtipoper and cab.dhtipoper=tpo.dhalter)
inner join tgfven ven on (ven.codvend = ite.codvend )
INNER JOIN TSICID CID ON (PAR.CODCID=CID.CODCID)
where cab.tipmov in ('V','D','T')
AND CAB.STATUSNOTA = 'L'
and cab.dtmov between trunc($P{Dtini}) and trunc($P{Dtfin})
and cab.codtipoper BETWEEN $P{Topini} AND $P{Topfin}
and cab.codemp= trunc($P{Empresa})
and pro.codprod = $P{Produto} or $P{Produto} is null
and ven.codvend = $P{Vendedor} or $P{Vendedor}  is null 
ORDER BY cab.DTMOV, cab.NUMNOTA
```

Answer (score 1):

Faltava você isolar com parenteses ( ) os parâmetro que serão nulos
Testa com o código abaixo;

```
    select
    TO_CHAR(cab.codparc,'00000000') AS CODPARC,
    par.razaosocial,
    TO_CHAR(cab.codparc,'00000000')||' - '||par.razaosocial as parceiro,
    par.razaosocial,
    TO_CHAR(cab.dtmov,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DATA,
    TO_CHAR(CAB.dtmov,'HH:MM') AS HORA,
    cab.codtipoper,
    cab.nunota,
    cab.numnota,
    cab.codemp,
    cab.tipmov,
    ite.codprod,
    pro.descrprod,
    ite.qtdneg,
    ite.codvol,
    ite.vlrunit,
    ven.apelido,
    cid.nomecid,
    pro.pesoliq,
    (ite.vlrtot-ite.vlrdesc)*(case when cab.tipmov='D' then -1 else 1 end) as vlrtot
    from tgfcab cab
    inner join tgfite ite on (ite.nunota=cab.nunota)
    inner join tgfpro pro on (ite.codprod=pro.codprod)
    inner join tgfpar par on (cab.codparc=par.codparc)
    inner join tgftop tpo on (cab.codtipoper=tpo.codtipoper and         cab.dhtipoper=tpo.dhalter)
    inner join tgfven ven on (ven.codvend = ite.codvend )
    INNER JOIN TSICID CID ON (PAR.CODCID=CID.CODCID)
    where cab.tipmov in ('V','D','T')
    AND CAB.STATUSNOTA = 'L'
    and cab.dtmov between trunc($P{Dtini}) and trunc($P{Dtfin})
    and cab.codtipoper BETWEEN $P{Topini} AND $P{Topfin}
    and cab.codemp= $P{Empresa}
    and (pro.codprod = $P{Produto} or $P{Produto} is null)
    and (ven.codvend = $P{Vendedor} or $P{Vendedor}  is null) 
    ORDER BY cab.DTMOV, cab.NUMNOTA
```